# SSIS Unique column?

Tags: sql, ssis, unique

Hello and sorry for newbie question.

I have a very simple SSIS project that imports customer names from file. It all works now fine, however there are multiple entries of same name and I dont want duplicates.

This works just fine, however it populates duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE [SLSales].[dbo].[Customer] (
id           BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name         NVARCHAR(100)   NOT NULL 
);
```

However, when I try to use this:

```
CREATE TABLE [SLSales].[dbo].[Customer] (
id           BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name         NVARCHAR(100)   NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

All records fail and I get a mysterious -1071607685 error code.

Comment: can you give some sample data and expected output

Comment: I'd have to guess it's failing on the unique constraint and rolling everything back.

Comment: You were absolutely right about the rollback thing. I tried with material that had no duplicate values and everything went fine with the latter table.

Now the next question is, if SSIS rollbacks all data when there are duplicates, what would be the wisest thing to prevent them?

Comment: I'd be curious if there's better answers out there, but my (hastily implemented) solution here was to import into your first table (no constraints, can be temp) and then run a sql statement that moves the rows into the second table from the first table with a where not in clause to eliminate the duplicate records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate rows from flat file using SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150760/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-flat-file-using-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

The SSIS way is to:

1. Load the data from Source
2. `GROUP BY [name]` in your case because you can have same name in file
3. Run through a Lookup (Match and NoMatch outputs)
4. Insert No Match
5. Update matches (or in your case you might want to just ignore)