# How to load mixed record type fixed width file with two headers into two separate files

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I got a task to load a strangely formatted text file. The file contains unwanted data too. It contains two headers back to back and data for each header is specified on alternate lines. Header rows start after `------`. I need to read both the header along with its corresponding data and dump it into some Excel/table destination using. Let me know how to solve this using any transformation in SSIS or maybe with a script.
Don't know how to use a script task for this.

Right now I am reading the file in one column and using a derived column manually trying to split it using `substring` function. But that works for only one header and it is too hard coded type. I need some dynamic approach to read header rows as well as data rows directly.

Input file:

```
A1234-012                                         I N F O R M A T I C S  C O M P A N Y                                      08/23/17
PAGE    2 BATCH ABC                                           PAYMENT DATE & DUE DATE                                 EDIT PAGE  481
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SEO  XRAT CLT     LOAN      OPENING  PAYMENT MATURIUH LOAN NEXE ORIG-AMT   OFF TO CATE  CONTC MON NO.TO  TOL NEL   S CUP CO IND PAT
 NOM  CODE NOM    NOMTER      DATE    DUO DATE  DATE   TIME PT #  MONEY         AQ LOAN  NUMBER    BLOCK   PAYMENT  U TYP GH OMG IND
       1-3 4-6  7-13/90-102  14-19    20-25     26-31 32-34 35-37 38-46   47-48 49 50-51 52-61  62  63      64-72  73 4-5 76 77 8-80
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SEO  XRAT CLT     LOAN     A/C   A/C     MIN     MAX    MAX   PENDI  LATE CCH  L/F  PARTLYS  CUR   L/F      L/F     L/F
 NOM  CODE NOM    NOMTER    CODE FACTOR   MON     MON    ROAD   DAYS  MONE POT  L/A  L/F JAC  INT  VAD CD  USED PI  VAD DT
       1-3 4-6  7-13/90-102  14  15      20-23   24-29   30-34 35-37   38-42    43     44     49     60     61-63    64-69
USED-ID:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
454542 070 567    2136547895 08-08-18 08-06-18 11-02-18 123 256      62,222  LK  5 55 5463218975 5 3       5,555.22    33        H55
025641 055 123    5144511352 B  .55321   2.55 6531.22                                                 H      #AS
454542 070 567    2136547895 08-08-18 08-06-18 11-02-18 123 256      62,222  LK  5 55 5463218975 5 3       5,555.22    33        H55
025641 055 123    5144511352 B  .55321   2.55 6531.22                                                 H      #AS
454542 070 567    2136547895 08-08-18 08-06-18 11-02-18 123 256      62,222  LK  5 55 5463218975 5 3       5,555.22    33        H55
025641 055 123    5144511352 B  .55321   2.55 6531.22                                                 H      #AS
```

Expected output should be:

FILE 1:

```
 SEO  XRAT CLT     LOAN      OPENING  PAYMENT MATURIUH LOAN NEXE ORIG-AMT   OFF TO CATE  CONTC MON NO.TO  TOL NEL   S CUP CO IND PAT
 NOM  CODE NOM    NOMTER      DATE    DUO DATE  DATE   TIME PT #  MONEY         AQ LOAN  NUMBER    BLOCK   PAYMENT  U TYP GH OMG IND
454542 070 567    2136547895 08-08-18 08-06-18 11-02-18 123 256      62,222  LK  5 55 5463218975 5 3       5,555.22    33        H55
454542 070 567    2136547895 08-08-18 08-06-18 11-02-18 123 256      62,222  LK  5 55 5463218975 5 3       5,555.22    33        H55
454542 070 567    2136547895 08-08-18 08-06-18 11-02-18 123 256      62,222  LK  5 55 5463218975 5 3       5,555.22    33        H55
```

FILE 2:

```
 SEO  XRAT CLT     LOAN     A/C   A/C     MIN     MAX    MAX   PENDI  LATE CCH  L/F  PARTLYS  CUR   L/F      L/F     L/F
 NOM  CODE NOM    NOMTER    CODE FACTOR   MON     MON    ROAD   DAYS  MONE POT  L/A  L/F JAC  INT  VAD CD  USED PI  VAD DT
025641 055 123    5144511352 B  .55321   2.55 6531.22                                                 H      #AS
025641 055 123    5144511352 B  .55321   2.55 6531.22                                                 H      #AS
025641 055 123    5144511352 B  .55321   2.55 6531.22                                                 H      #AS
```

[image: Output:File 1]
[image: Output:File 2]
[image: sample data]

Comment: What is the bounty expectation? I think that i have provided a very detailed answer which gives the OP desired result. In addition i provided many updates based on the OP comments which are not mentioned in the original question.

Comment: You provided a good and detailed answer. But, i opened the bounty in order to draw more attention and to see if there is other approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: @user6423884 did the provided answer solved the issue? If so [why you didn't accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Answer (score 5):

### Ignore first 3 rows

To ignore first 3 rows you can simply configure the flat file connection manager to ignore them, similar to:

[image]

---

### Split file and remove bad rows

**1. Configure connection managers**

In addition, in the flat file connection manager, go to the advanced tab and delete all columns except one and change its data type to `DT_STR` and the MaxLength to `4000`.

[image]

Add two connection managers , one for each destination file where you must define only one column with max length = 4000:

[image]

[image]

**2. Configure Data flow task**

Add a Data Flow Task, And add a Flat File Source inside. Select the Source File connection manager.

Add a conditional split with the following expressions:

*File1*

```
FINDSTRING([Column 0],"OPENING",1) > 1 || FINDSTRING([Column 0],"DATE",1) > 1 || TOKENCOUNT([Column 0]," ") == 19
```

*File2*

```
FINDSTRING([Column 0],"A/C",1) > 1 || FINDSTRING([Column 0],"FACTOR",1) > 1 || TOKENCOUNT([Column 0]," ") == 10
```

[image]

The expressions above are created based on the expected output you mentioned in the question, i tired to search for unique keywords inside each header and splitted the data rows based on the number of space occurrence.

Finally Map each output to a destination flat file component:

[image]

### Experiments

The execution result is shown in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

---

### Update 1 - Remove duplicates

To remove duplicates you must you can refer to the following link:

- [How to remove duplicate rows from flat file using SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150760/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-flat-file-using-ssis)

---

## Update 2 - Remove only duplicates headers + Replace spaces with Tab

If you need only to remove duplicate headers then you can do this in two steps:

1. Add a script component after each conditional split output to flag unwanted rows
2. Add a conditional split to filter rows based on the script component output

In addition, because the columns values does not contains spaces you can use regular expression to replace spaces with single Tab to make the file consistent.

**Script Component**

In the Script Component add an output column of type DT_BOOL and name it `outFlag` also add a output column `outColumn0` of type `DT_STR` and length equal to `4000` and select `Column0` as Input Column.

[image]

[image]

Then write the following script in the Script Editor *(C#)*:

*First make sure that you add the RegularExpressions namespace*

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

*Script Code*

```
int SEOCount = 0;
int NOMCount = 0;

Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);


public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (Row.Column0.Trim().StartsWith("SEO"))
    {


        if (SEOCount == 0)
        {

            SEOCount++;
            Row.outFlag = true;

        }
        else
        {

            Row.outFlag = false;

        }



    }
    else if (Row.Column0.Trim().StartsWith("NOM"))
    {

        if (NOMCount == 0)
        {

            NOMCount++;
            Row.outFlag = true;

        }
        else
        {

            Row.outFlag = false;

        }

    }
    else if (Row.Column0.Trim().StartsWith("PAGE"))
    {
        Row.outFlag = false;
    }
    else
    {

        Row.outFlag = true;

    }


    Row.outColumn0 = regex.Replace(Row.Column0.TrimStart(), "\t");
}
```

*Conditional Split*

Add a conditional split after each Script Component and use the following expression to filter duplicate header:

```
[outFlag] == True
```

And connect the conditional split to the destination. **Make Sure to map `outColumn0` to the destination column.**

[image]

**Package link**

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/d936u4xo3mkzns8/Package.dtsx?dl=0

Comment: Thank you Hadi for your response. Your solution is pretty much near to what I am expecting but I want output in Excel file. So main problem here is to parse multiple spaces and store them in excel file as separate column.

Comment: also in original file this data is getting repeated along with the header multiple times.Attaching an image to show the data.

Comment: @user6423884 to remove duplicates headers you need to add a script component, i will add it to my answer in a while. Concerning Excel destination just change the flat file extension to csv and it can be opened with excel.

Comment: @user6423884 check the answer update. There are other solutions then script component

Comment: No no...I want to pull all the data....the pattern(i.e. same two headers, but with different data on alternate line) is getting repeated but need to pull all the data.  Steps:1.Read source file ->2.read first header along with its data and dump it into one table  ->3.read another header along with its data and dump into another table(table containing each column in separate cell ..i have attached screenshot shot of output with separate columns.)->Avoid all unwanted data.Finally, we have to dump data into tables. We are dumping it in excel just for testing.

Comment: Basically file contains some good data (which is split across multiple section with same header rows but different data) and some bad data. We have to fetch two header rows and its corresponding data that is available on alternate rows. Create two destination table(one for each header along with its data) and dump data in it. rest things i have mentioned in above comment. and thanks a lot for taking out time and responding to my queries.

Comment: @user6423884 i didn't get it. What is the problem you faced in my solution? Just add one sort component after each conditional split output and check the remove duplicates option.

Comment: I am not able to clarify it properly. There is no duplicate data at alll. I want to fetch whole data within the file and dump it into table in separate columns.Now when i try fetching output in excel(for testing), data is exported to one column only ..not on separate column.I just wanted to check if it is ok for you, is there any other way to communicate ? ... I can more specifically explain above issue

Comment: @user6423884 then you need to add a script component with a conditional split. I will update my answer tonight

Comment: Hi Hadi... I have created more specific samples for i/p n o/p ...and more detailed information of how o/p is required.If you can share your email id ,I will share it with you , as i am not able to attach it here.

Comment: @user6423884 wait for my answer update. If you need to share the file. Upload it to dropbox or google drive and share a link. It is better than sending via email

Comment: Hi Hadi..sure once d problem is solved i ll vote it. I ll try the solution that u have provided...but again as i can see problem lies in the output (i want data to be in separate column mostly in sql table..but for testing excel will work but with data on separate column)..fetch both header rows from d file only once (separate table/excel for each header)and then fetch corresponding data for those header throughout d whole file(by ignoring irrelevant data)..I am sharing a link to dropbox which will give u more clarity-> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hyyfiehuklq0wh3/AADt1hUj1OZK_4UDsbiujmpca?dl=0

Comment: @user6423884 i checked the files provided, the last update will gives you the expected output. But there is one problem: the header is splitted into 2 rows since that is the source format.

Comment: Hi Hadi....I implemented the solution but it is not removing duplicate headers.It is pulling data but for every new section header is getting repeated as it is in the source file. Also it is not giving expected output in excel(the one i have provided in dropbox) with each column in different cell.When loaded to excel destination ,all data is loaded into one column only.I don't want to load final output either in flat file destination or in one column of excel. It should be in different cell as mentioned.

Comment: @user6423884 i tested it one the file you provided and it is giving the excpected output. Also use flat file destination (.csv not txt) and open it with excel

Comment: @user6423884 https://superuser.com/questions/238944/how-to-force-excel-to-open-csv-files-with-data-arranged-in-columns

Comment: Can you share the package that you created using the input file that i provided(may be in dropbox or anywhere it is ok with you)..because for me its not working. It will be helpful to see what i am missing out in my package.

Comment: @user6423884 i updated my answer and added the package link, also i made an improvement since i replaced all spaces occurrence with a single tab to make the file structure consistent. The package are created under sql server 2016 / visual studio 2015

Comment: Hi Hadi, I have checked your packg..it eliminates duplicate header concept but gives output in csv file in format that is different from expected one. It clubs most of the columns in one column and also data is not aligned with its column(i.e column name is somewhere else and data smwhere else). I am attaching files/snapshots of current and expected output at below dropbox link(under folder "sample_files"):  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i81iraf3y3go352/AAAVbjlQ7rc0x17fjTEF4Nv9a?dl=0 
Current output(dest1_output,dest2_output)   Expected Output(AUTOMATION_file1_img,AUTOMATION_file2_img)

Comment: final requirement is to load the data into separate columns in table.There are few columns for which there is no data,so we have to keep those columns as blank (only column name should be there no data for them). Rest output should be as shown in screenshots in drop box.

Comment: Thank you for your help,will dig into it further. And thank you for your patience and responding every time to the query.